# Why are dropzoneJS resize options having no affect?

Tags: dropzone.js, ruby-on-rails-6

I have drop zone working in a rails 6 app with ActiveStorage and Stimulus.  However, the resizeHeight and resizeQuality don't seem to have any affect on the uploaded image.

In the settings illustrated below, Im expecting the final image to be small with low quality.  However, I get back the same image I originally attached.  No compression or size changes at all.

Also, I'm curious if will DropzoneJS upsize?  Or, if by default it will not upsize?  Also, is it smart enough to skip resize options for non-images?  The docs don't specify.

My Dropzone_controller looks like this:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import Dropzone from "dropzone"
import 'dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css'
import 'dropzone/dist/min/basic.min.css'
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input"]

  connect() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false

    this.inputTarget.disable = true
    this.inputTarget.style.display = "none"
    const dropzone = new Dropzone(this.element, {
      url: '/',
      maxFiles: 10,
      maxFilesize: 6,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      resizeHeight: 50,
      resizeQuality: 0.1,
      autoQueue: false
    })

    dropzone.on("addedfile", file => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (file.accepted) {
          const upload = new DirectUpload(file, this.url)
          upload.create((error, blob) => {
            this.hiddenInput = document.createElement("input")
            this.hiddenInput.type = "hidden"
            this.hiddenInput.name = this.inputTarget.name
            this.hiddenInput.value = blob.signed_id
            this.inputTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(this.hiddenInput, this.inputTarget.nextSibling)
            dropzone.emit("success", file)
            dropzone.emit("complete", file)
          })
        }
      }, 500)
    })
  }

  get url() {
    return this.inputTarget.getAttribute('data-direct-upload-url')
  }
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`resizeWidth` and `resizeHeight` have no effect because setting `autoqueue: false` bypasses this part of the Dropzone source code.